# ExpiresHeader .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am currently trying to improve website loading times and I am using the following:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>    
############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
    Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2020 20:00:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

That works great ... I was wondering if it is possible not to have a fixed date there. Can I do something like this?

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 years"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Doesn't seem to work ATM :S

Thanks

Regards
Gabriel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable `ExpiresDefault`, you need to set [`ExpiresActive`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html#expiresactive) to `on` as in:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 years"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

---

The above answer should solve your question. For other cases: `mod_expires` is not a default Apache module, it's an [extension](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html). Make sure that it is enabled, which you can do using `phpinfo()` on a PHP-enabled server. If you have shell access, you can run `apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES`.

Comment: Hi in the mean time we came up with another solution which I wanted to share with you.

ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 10 years"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 10 years"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 10 years"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 10 years"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 10 years"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 10 years"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 10 years"

What do you think?

Comment: @ElGabbu: Looks good, but I would not set an expires time of 10 years, 1 year is fine. Not that it really matters, but in 10 years a lot can change.

Comment: Agreed I set it 1 year now. Thanks for your help. :)